# Updating the AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute of an exe

Tags: .net, assemblyinfo

Is it possible to update an EXEs AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute? I'm trying to include additional information in the setup.exe output from an InstallAware project rather than just the standard 4 digit version info.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you want to update it before or after the build. If you want to change it prior to compilation in a C# project, just add it to your `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Vista and Server 2008's Windows Explorer has bug. It displays AssemblyInformationalVersion as 0.0.0.0 if the format is not A.B.C.D
Sometimes we may want to put versions like 1.2-beta, v2.10.2-g77d3fa9 in AssemblyInformationalVersion.